# How do I use an ATMega 328 (not P) chip with an Arduino board?

Tags: atmega328, avr

I just burned the bootloader on an ATMega328 chip and then I put in on the Arduino board. But when I try to upload a program to it, it says programmer not in sync and programmer not responding.

For burning the bootloader I changed the address in the avrconfig file and reset it back to the original one. Do I need to keep changing the address of the board?

How do I use this as a normal Arduino board, as I fried my original chip? Do I need to get an ATMega328P chip?

Comment: Did you set the right fuses for the clock source?

Comment: i used an external 16mhz clock but didnt change any code for it.

Comment: If you don't set the right fuses it will be running from the internal clock and everything will be the wrong speed. Check your fuse settings.

Comment: @Majenko could you help me with this i am a bit new to this.

Answer (score 2):

So I found the solution:

Here is [the link](http://3g1l.com/blog-burn-bootloader-blank-atmega328atmega328p-arduino-uno) to the method that worked for me. I think the reason my previous method didn't work was because of fuses for the clock as mentioned by Majenko in the comments.

Comment: thank you for showing me how i am supposed to answer (i am new here).

Answer (score 0):

You can force the 'P' bootloader into it and use it as an Arduino board. The extra possibilities of the 'P' are not used by the standard Arduino libraries and when uploading it does check the bootloader but it does not check the chip signature.

I think you have already done this. Perhaps something else is wrong.